# Using both 24VDC and 5VDC

Tags: voltage, split

I am working on a circuit board powered by 5VDC. Since the product will be used in the industrial area, there is a 24VDC energy supply. In addition, the user can connect the device to the computer via USB by cutting the 24VDC power during certain definitions. Naturally, the device must be able to detect different voltages on the same line and send 5 VDC to the system.

I can make 24VDC voltage, 5VDC with the help of a regulator. But when 5VDC on the USB line comes to this regulator input, the regulator cannot give the same voltage from the output, so I can't get the result I want.

If I set up a circuit for this system and disconnect the USB energy without entering the regulator, the voltage drop in the diodes I will use at the junction of the energies still does not provide the 5VDC voltage I want. [image]

As can be seen from the diagram, the input is single and if you give 24VDC, it goes directly to the voltage regulator and then to the diode, and if you give it 5VDC, it goes directly to the diode. Do you mind if I disable the array diode?

Comment: The question might not be what kind of regulator you should use, but how to design such a circuit that accepts 5V directly or generates 5V from 24V, but most circuits work with 3.3V anyway so is 5V really required? What circuit is it?

Comment: After regulating the input voltage, I direct it to the VUSB input. That's why I chose 5VDC.

Answer (score 4):

> *What kind of regulator should I use?*

It seems likely that you can use a [4 switch buck-boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter#Principles_of_operation_of_the_four-switch_topology). They operate from an input supply that is a little below 5 volts to a higher input voltage such as 24 volts. Of course you need to pick the right device and ensure that it can handle the current you load produces.

[This one from Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/dfrobot/dfr0205/dc-dc-power-module/dp/3769970?gclid=CjwKCAjwt52mBhB5EiwA05YKo83ljnum2N03OxPKh-kYmSjnMmL_Otb7gLoVM7gAvfs6fnQo4qxYdhoCIWwQAvD_BwE&mckv=_dc%7Cpcrid%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7C3769970%7Cpgrid%7C%7Cptaid%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-PMAX-Medium_ROAS-Test990&gross_price=true) can convert any DC voltage between 3.6V-25V to a selectable voltage from 3.3V to 25V: -

[image]

It's just an example of the type of circuit board you can buy off the shelf.

Comment: In the product I designed, I do not have an area where I can mount this ready-made card you mentioned.

Comment: @erkan well you have to make a decision; build or buy. If you can't buy because it won't fit then you have to build it to fit into the room you have.